# Why do I get `Bad file descriptor` when copying using hardlink flag?

Tags: terminal, filesystem

Every once in a while I find that I need to use the `-rl` options of `cp` to clone a directory tree using hardlinks. This has always worked fine on Linux, and I can see that the BSD `cp` command accepts the same options. When I try to link a file on macOS, I get:

```
cp -l  release-source/release/examples/stubs-1-pubsub.test.js .
cp: ./stubs-1-pubsub.test.js: Bad file descriptor
```

This made it seem like the copying failed, but `ls` shows it went fine:

```
ls -li  release-source/release/examples/stubs-1-pubsub.test.js stubs-1-pubsub.test.js
9825657 -rw-r--r--  2 carlerik  staff  1072 26 sep 16:24 release-source/release/examples/stubs-1-pubsub.test.js
9825657 -rw-r--r--  2 carlerik  staff  1072 26 sep 16:24 stubs-1-pubsub.test.js
```

So ... what is going on?

**System information**

```
❯ npx envinfo --system

  System:
    OS: macOS 13.5.2
    CPU: (12) arm64 Apple M2 Max
    Memory: 4.24 GB / 64.00 GB
    Shell: 5.2.15 - /opt/homebrew/bin/bash

❯ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         2.0 TB     disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s3
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm on macOS Sonoma and I used to use the command `cp -al dirA dirB` on earlier OSes, but it doesn't seem to work anymore, giving the same error `Bad file descriptor`

Comment: On the Apple forum a developer said that's a bug I need to report. Works anyway 

Comment: @oligofren what do you mean by saying "works anyway?"

Comment: @OionAkif Did you read the above? I write that nothing seems functionally wrong from inspection, yet I do get an error message.

Comment: Until this is fixed, you can install the coreutils package with homebrew and use `gcp` in place of `cp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This has been submitted as bug to Apple:](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738452?page=1#773563022) [FB13434700](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/13434700)